# (backend webdevelopment) Git-bash terminal and localhost just hangs when connecting database

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash, express, localhost

Here is all the code that is there:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
//const port = 3000;

const leaderboardDb = mysql.createConnection({
    //host    : 'localhost',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user    : 'root',
    password: 'personalProj15',
    port    : '3000',
    database: 'test'
    //socketPath: '/tmp/mysql.sock'
})


leaderboardDb.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('MySQL connected');
    }
}) 

const app = express();

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server started (on 3000)');
})


app.get('/createDb', (request, response) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE leaderboardDatabase';
    leaderboardDb.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) { throw err}
        else {
            console.log(result);
            response.send("Testing...");
        }
    })
})
```

"Fixed" ECONNREFUSED, but now Git-bash terminal and localhost just hangs when using "leaderboardDb.connect((err)". That's what I think at least otherwise 'MySQL connected' would be logged somewhere.

Notes:

- <s>The error is being thrown from leaderboardDb.connect</s>
- If I get pass that error git-bash and "localhost:3000/createDb" just hangs
- I am in VScode, installed mysql and express thru npm

Things I have tried/looked at:

- I listened on port 3306 instead and changed port to 3306 (port:3306) but git-bash just hangs.

  - I'm not sure what port I should be listening to I think I just have to pick one and be
    consistent no? (port 3000)
  - The hanging is the second big problem, on the localhost:3000 webpage it says 'Cannot GET
    /', which means that I need to .connect, right? I try "localhost:3000/createDb"
    and it just hangs

+ Some solutions suggested `socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` and a different path that involved `/tmp/mysql.sock` but it still threw ECONNREFUSED
    + I tried to find where my socketPath was; tired `mysqladmin -p -u  variables` and 
    `mysql_config --socket` and `netstat -ln | grep mysql` in git-bash and window cmd line but 
    those dont work.
    + Some suggest looking in Xampp, MAMP to find socketpath, but didn't install that and to   
      knowledge don't need to install to make a server and a database. Can't I just find the  
      socket path in windows cmd line/git-bash?

- Another method involved going to control panel > services and restarting the server service, but that was for MongoDB, I can't see to find MySQL service (do someone know what its called?)

Maybe I need to configure firewall, but I'm not savvy with that, so I hope any suggestions there will not compromise my security/

*(Overall I built a website and I'm just trying to create the backend server, create a Db in it, send it some requests, store that info, and send some queried info back)

Comment: try 3306 but you have amy.cnf which has all the configuration data

Comment: I listened on 3306 and changed port:3306 as well but it still hangs. How do you know that I have amy.cnf (how would I check that) and do I use that to find my socketpath? I'm confused on what I do with "amy.cnf" info

Comment: every mysql server and also mariadb has such a file look for your operating system and my.cnf

Comment: is the file supposed to be on my computer locally I can't seem to find it after searching file explorer; also I'm not sure why I'm looking for this can you explain?

Comment: like i saud it depends on the operating system a search with it and my.cnf will help you find it

Comment: That is *not* bash syntax.  Unclear...  As a first step, make sure your mysql is installed, running, and you can connect to it directly using mysql tools.  Than validate that your port is in LISTEN, and not blocked by any firewall.  *Then* look into coding something.